# d3 pack - make bubbles set more flat (take less height)

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to flat abit the `pack` layout?

This is what I have: 
[image: bubbles]

And this is what I want:

[image: bubbles]

As you can see the second set of bubbles is more flat.. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: How do you get from "Chicken Salad" to "Pets"?

Comment: ignore the content.. just want the `pack` to take less height and more widht

Comment: [pack.size(size)](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#pack_size)

Comment: Tried that. Size only gives the size to the svg container, this causes the circles to get cut. this not arrange them inside the container

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't do it with `d3.pack`, but you can achieve a similar layout using the `d3-force`:

```js
var numNodes = 30;
var nodes = d3.range(numNodes).map(function(d, i) {
  return {
    color: '#55c',
    radius: Math.random() * 12 + 12
  }
});

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(10))
  .force('y', d3.forceY().y(0))
  .force('collision',
    d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
      return d.radius + 1;
    }))
  .on('tick', ticked);

function ticked() {
  var u = d3.select('svg g')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes);

  var v = u.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', function(d) {
      return d.radius;
    })
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return d.color;
    })
    .merge(u)
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })

  u.exit().remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <svg width="400" height="200">
    <g transform="translate(200, 100)"></g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks good, but I do have one issue with it.
this way layout is different on every render and sometime its too flat.. is there a way to control that?

Comment: how likely is it that the number of nodes change during the force simulation? Create the circles outside `tick` and just update the `cx` and `cy` inside the `tick`

Comment: @rioV8 the number of nodes doesnt change. But how this will help? there are still cases where it too flat

Comment: Manage to solve it with `.attr('cx', function(d) { 
     return d.x = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x))
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y));
    })`. this way I can control with the height and width of the container how flat are the circles https://jsfiddle.net/dz871gns/33/